# How to access a private git repo in cloud run build

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have a python Cloud Run container with a private git repo as a dependency. I have found docs of how to use private repos in [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/access-github-from-build) but am yet to find what is best practice for doing the same thing in a Cloud Run container.

EDIT: extra information as requested in comments.

The container uses a private git repo at build time as a dependency from `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Please elaborate more the use case. Your web container uses at build time or run time the private git repo? The guide you linked applies to Cloud Run runtime as well. You store your key in Secret Manager, and your application pulls the key, and runs the git operation. Technicall the context is the same, the article can be applied 1:1 for your problem on Cloud Run as well.

Comment: @Pentium10 Added some more information as you requested.

Comment: Did you tried the tutorial you linked? What errors you got? That's the way to do it.

Comment: How do you build with "Cloud run build"? Do you use the command `gcloud run deploy --source=. ...` and let Cloud Run builds your container for you?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I use the `gcloud run build` followed by a `gcloud run deploy` :)

Comment: You need to switch to Cloud Build based on the tutorial you linked and run `gcloud builds submit` with the YAML file steps

Comment: `gcloud run build ` doesn't exist. Thus my question!

Comment: Yes sorry @guillaumeblaquiere `gcloud builds submit` is what I am using.

Comment: Ok, I better understand and therefore the comment of @Pentium10 is the right one: you need a `cloudbuild.yaml` file and to customize your authentication in a step (if you need credential, use secret manager for that)

Comment: @Pentium10 Is there a simplified flow when using github actions?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere would you happen to know another option or flow apart from the one I linked, specifically when using GH actions?

Comment: You can link your Github repo with your Google Cloud project in Cloud Build and therefore you have a mirror in your project and therefore your have immediately the source code when you run your build, no authentication needed in your Cloud Build. But it's true only if your private repo is the repo to build. If you are dependent to another private repos, it doesn't work. Github action could solve thing, but I didn't know how it manage the security access to the other private repo, which credentials are used.

Comment: I see that here there is a possible answer for this issue, it would be so helpful if we could summarize it in an answer to help the community.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere so I have tried to connect my repo to cloud build, herehttps://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/repos this works, but still when I use `gcloud builds submit` and my requirements.txt file contains a link to the githube repo I see an auth error - am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

#### Which is the best practice to use a private repository in a Cloud Run container?

The [guide](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/access-github-from-build) that you shared about how to use private repositories in Cloud Build [also applies to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run#building_and_deploying_a_container), you can follow it as if it was for Cloud Run.
You can customize the authentication inside a step in the [cloudbuild.yaml file](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema). If you want to keep your credentials safe, what you have to do is to store your private SSH key in the [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager), and your application will pull the key and authenticate git to run the operation.

#### Is there a simplified flow when using github actions?

A simplified flow is linking your Github repository with your Google Cloud project CLoud Build, doing this you will be able to have a mirror in your project and you’ll get the source code immediately after running your build. As the Github repository is already linked you won’t need any authentication step, but this only works if the repository to build it is one of your private repositories, it won’t work if the private repository is called from a dependency.

---

This answer was created to make the solution given in the comments more visible to the community.